# azure mobile service blob storage using xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, azure-blob-storage, azure-mobile-services

I have used the info on this link to create a windows phone sample of uploading images to Azure Blob Storage by using Mobile Services.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/upload-images-to-storage-wp8/

I want to now try and use Xamarin Component of Azure Mobile Services to achieve the same result from Android and iOS. Does Xamarin component have support for this? Also, if anyone has done this before from Xamarin, could you please point me in the correct direction? I couldn't find much information on this topic of using blob storage from within Xamarin for Android or iOS

Answer (score 4):

You can use Zach's Blob Uploader:

```
https://github.com/zgramana/IOSAzureBlobUploader
```

This is a lot simpler than using the AMS features for this (but lacks the features like expiration of the url and some auth bits).

Comment: Hi Miguel, thanks for your response. I would like to upload images to Azure blog storage from Android as well as iOS apps. Similar to the instructions provided on windowsazure (link in my question), how can I do this from Xamarin component for AMS?

Comment: I guess, how to go about doing this for Android and Windows Azure Blob Storage using Xamarin.Android?

Answer (score 0):

You really want to use a web service between your blob storage account, and your Mobile app, unless your app is allowing users to access their own blob storage accounts.  If you are determined to make a Xamarin app use Blob storage directly, you can use this Mono port.. it takes a bit of work to get it functioning.  It also won't handle some functions in Azure Blob storage.  I could only get "Download" to work. Deleting.. and uploading functions were broken. Maybe I screwed up the port to Xamarin.

[Mono Azure sdk port](https://github.com/richorama/azure-sdk-for-mono)

By using that sdk port, I was able to make an IOS app called "Blob Client" that allowed users to at least download their files on IOS.  Made it as a tool for myself.. for a project I had, but then went ahead and put it out on the store.

[Blob Client on IOS.](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blob-client/id695896662?mt=8)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article on connecting to Blog Storage in Xamarin via the Azure Storage package.  It's currently in preview but should be what you are looking for.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-xamarin-blob-storage/